# Understanding POSIX - fork()

Tags: c, operating-system, fork, posix

I was reading about the `fork` function and how it creates new processes. The following program runs fine and prints `here` sixteen times, but, I am having trouble understanding the flow of execution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h> 

int main() 
{ 
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) { // line no. 12
        fork();               // line no. 13
    }
    printf("%s\n", "here");
    return 0; 
}
```

It seems to me that there are two ways this program can be viewed as:

1st approach: `fork()` is called a total of four times. If I replace the loop with four calls to the `fork()` function, things seem to fall in place and I understand why `here` is printed `2 ^ 4` times.

2nd approach: `fork()` spawns a new process exactly from where it is invoked and each of these child processes have their own local variables. So, after line no. 13, each of these child processes see the end of the loop (`}`) and they go to line no. 12. Since, all these child processes have their own local variable `i` set to 0 (maybe `i` is set to some garbage value?), they all fork again. Again for these child processes their local variable `i` is set to 0. This should result in a [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb).

I am certainly missing something in my 2nd approach could someone please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your 2nd approach is not right. Because after `fork()` the child process inherits the *current* value of `i`. It's nneither set to `0` everytime `fork()` is called nor do they have garbage value. So, your code can't have a fork bomb. The fact that it's a local variable is irrelevant. `fork()` *clones* pretty much everything and the child process is identical to its parent except for certain things as noted in the [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) manual.

I'll reduce the loop count to 2 for ease of explaining and assume all `fork()` calls succeed:

```
   for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        fork();
    }
    printf("%s\n", "here");
```

1) When `i=0`, `fork()` is executed and there are two processes now. Call them P1 and P2.

2) Now, each P1 and P2 processes continue with i=0 the loop and increment `i` to 1. The `for` loop condition is true, so each of them spawn another two processes and in total 4. Call them  P1a & P1b and P2a & P2b. All 4 processes now have i=1 and increment it to 2 (as they continue the loop).

3) Now, all 4 processes have the value of `i` as 2 and for loop condition is false in all of them and "here" will be printed 4 times (one by each process).

If it helps, you can convert the `for` loop to a `while` loop and how `i` gets incremented by *both* processes returning from each `fork()` might become a bit more clear:

```
    i = 0;
   while(i < 2) {
        fork();
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", "here");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach was right.
That's a rather boring answer, so I'll give you all the technical details.

When `fork` is called, several things happen:

- A new process is created ('the child')
- The stack of the parent is duplicated, and assigned to the child.
- The stack pointer of the child is set to that of the parent.
- The PID (process ID) of the child is returned to the parent.
- Zero is returned to the child

variables declared **inside** a function are stored in the stack, and are therefore start at the same value, but are *not* shared.
variables declared **outside** a function (at the top level) are not in the stack, so are shared between child/parent.

(Some other things are or are not duplicated; see `man fork` for more information.)

So, when you run your code:

```
    what happens                    # of processes  
1. the parent forks.                2  
2. the parent and it's child fork.  4  
3. everyone forks                   8  
4. everyone forks                   16  
5. everyone prints "here".          16
```

You end up with sixteen processes, and the word 'here' sixteen times.

basically,

```
if(fork() != 0) {
    parent_stuff();
} else {
    child_stuff();
}
```

Comment: When you say that 'variables declared outside a function are shared', do you mean that any writes by the child to that variable will be visible to the parent process? If you do mean that, I think you are wrong. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: I'm 99% sure it's correct, but `man fork` doesn't say anything about it.

Comment: Then how would you explain the output of the program listed here: http://hastebin.com/owedavelob.xml

Answer (score 0):

Using following code and you can easily see how fork create the value of variable i:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("%d %s\n", i, "here");
    fork();              
}
```

As what you could expect, the child process copy the value of parent process and so we get 0 line with i = 0; 2 lines with i = 1; 4 lines with i = 2 and 8 lines with i = 3. Which I think answers your 2nd question.